# Exception when I do a list operation

Tags: java, list, exception

I have following class

I am monitoring a queue. When a message got enqueued I log it and when a message got dequeued the same. This code works for 75% correct.Sometimes a file gets enqueue too much, but this isn't the main problem case.

Now let's take a look at the following code, first I make a connection with the queue, than I add message ids to my list when I enqueue my queue. If the list is bigger than the queue size (which I count every time I loop it), a dequeue needs to happen. A helplist copies first the arraylist and removes all the items it encounters on the queue. The items it didn't encounter, are from the queue, so they need to get dequeued from the list. If the list is not bigger, I check if the id is already in the list, if it isn't I make a new enqueue.

```
package queueFeed;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;

import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.QueueBrowser;
import javax.jms.Session;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class QueueRunner {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(QueueRunner.class.getName());



    public void run() throws Exception {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61616");
        javax.jms.Connection connection =  factory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(new ActiveMQQueue("KBC"));

        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        int queueSize = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        connection.start();
        while(true) {

        Enumeration enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
            if(queueSize < ids.size())
            {
                List<String> checkList = ids;
                while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                    Message message = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
                    checkList.remove(message.getJMSMessageID());
                    counter++;
                }

                if(checkList.size() > 0 && ids.size() > 0)
                for(String notEncountered : checkList) {
                    ids.remove(notEncountered);
                    System.out.println("dequeued " + notEncountered);
                }
                queueSize = counter;
                counter = 0;
            }
            else {

                while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                    counter++;
                Message message = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
                String id = message.getJMSMessageID();
                if (!ids.contains(id)) {
                    ids.add(id);
                    System.out.println("enqueued message" + message.getJMSMessageID());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
                queueSize = counter;
        counter = 0;
    }
}}}
```

When I dequeue I get following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at queueFeed.QueueRunner.run(QueueRunner.java:43)
    at dashboard.Main.main(Main.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The error points at line 43, which is the for(String notEncountered : helpList) line...  What is wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a normal for loop it's impossible to remove items from a list.
You need to use an Iterator for doing this performances.

You replace your normal for loop by

```
if(checkList.size() > 0 && ids.size() > 0)
                {
                    Iterator<String> iterator = checkList.iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String messageId = iterator.next();
                        System.out.println("dequeued message "+ messageId);
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify a List in a loop you either have to

Create a temporary List you run over:

```
List<Integer> tmpList = copyOf(myList);

for(int n : tmpList){
    if(myList.contains(n) && SomethingIsTrue()){
        myList.remove(n);
    }
}
```

or you have to run backwards through your list

```
for(int i = myList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(SomethingIsTrue()){
        myList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Note this is pseudo code (having some methods for checks etc)

Running over a List and modifying it, you change the index of its items when removing others. Thats why you get the `ConcurrentModificationException`

In your example you say:

```
List<String> checkList = ids;
```

So `checkList` and `ids` are equal. If you remove something from `ids`, but run over `checkList`, you still run over the same object. You have to create a copy of the `ids` List to get the temporary behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove items with a range-based loop. Use a Iterator.

```
Iterator<String> it = ids.iterator();
while(it.hasNext){
    if(checkList.contains(it.next()) it.remove();
}
```

Instead of

```
for(String notEncountered : checkList) {
                    ids.remove(notEncountered);
                    System.out.println("dequeued " + notEncountered);
                }
```

Comment: Makes sense, going to try it

Comment: @Guil No problem. Mark this answer as helpful and have fun.